# Help me In recovering

Tags: salat, practical-islam, allah, dua

Hello Brothers and Sisters,

I am writing here as a resort for help. I dont know what to do. months ago i got involved in things I shouldn't have, I had been talking with a guy from my middle eastern community and my family had made me cut things off between us because it wasn't right. I repented over and over again, and I have been pulled closer to islam. However, why do I cry over "missing" the person. I dont know why my heart feels broken. I have been asking Allah to help me heal and bring me closer to islam, but what do i do....if i constantly feel anxiety over missing the person, knowing he's moved on and doesn't care.

Comment: This is not a support group.